# Replacing nth instance of a character string using sub/gsub in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am attempting to re-name some character strings given to me in a large list. The issue is that I only need to replace some of the characters not all of them.

```
exdata <- c("i_am_having_trouble_with_this_string",
            "i_am_wishing_files_were_cleaner_for_me",
            "any_help_would_be_greatly_appreciated")
```

From this list, for example, I would like to replace the third through the fifth instance of "_" with "-". I am having trouble understanding the regex coding for this, as most examples split strings up instead of keeping them intact.

Comment: Have a look at `gsubfn` if you want to use a regex for this.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some alternative approaches.  All of them can be generalized to arbitrary bounds by replacing 3 and 5 with other numbers.

**1) strsplit**  Split the strings at underscore and use `paste` to collapse it back using the appropriate separators.  No packages are used.

```
i <- 3
j <- 5
sapply(strsplit(exdata, "_"), function(x) {
  g <- seq_along(x)
  g[g < i] <- i
  g[g > j + 1] <- j+1
  paste(tapply(x, g, paste, collapse = "_"), collapse = "-")
})
```

giving:

```
[1] "i_am_having-trouble-with-this_string"  
[2] "i_am_wishing-files-were-cleaner_for_me"
[3] "any_help_would-be-greatly-appreciated"
```

**2) for loop** This translates the first j occurrences of `old` to `new` in `x` and then translates the first i-1 occurrences of `new` back to `old`.   No packages are used.

```
translate <- function(old, new, x, i = 1, j) {
 if (i <= 1) {
    if (j > 0) for(k in seq_len(j)) x <- sub(old, new, x, fixed = TRUE)
    x
 } else Recall(new, old, Recall(old, new, x, 1, j), 1, i-1)
}

translate("_", "-", exdata, 3, 5)
```

giving:

```
[1] "i_am_having-trouble-with-this_string"  
[2] "i_am_wishing-files-were-cleaner_for_me"
[3] "any_help_would-be-greatly-appreciated"
```

**3) gsubfn**  This uses a package but in return is substantially shorter than the others.  `gsubfn` is like `gsub` except that the replacement string in `gsub` can be a string, list, function or proto object. In the case of a proto object the `fun` method of the proto object is invoked each time there is a match to the regular expression.  Below the matching string is passed  to `fun` as `x` while the output of `fun` replaces the match in the data.  The proto object is automatically populated with a number of variables set by `gsubfn` and accessible by `fun` including `count` which is 1 for the first match, 2 for the second and so on. For more information see the [gsubfn vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/vignettes/gsubfn.pdf) -- section 4 discusses the use of proto objects.

```
library(gsubfn)

p <- proto(i = 3, j = 5, 
      fun = function(this, x) if (count >= i && count <= j) "-" else x)
gsubfn("_", p, exdata)
```

giving:

```
[1] "i_am_having-trouble-with-this_string"  
[2] "i_am_wishing-files-were-cleaner_for_me"
[3] "any_help_would-be-greatly-appreciated"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> gsub('(.*_.*_.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*)','\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4', exdata)
[1] "i_am_having-trouble-with-this_string"   "i_am_wishing-files-were-cleaner_for_me" "any_help_would-be-greatly-appreciated"
```

Comment: Could you explain the regex a bit for this? I.e. if I wanted to use this for the 4th through the 6th, 2nd and 3rd, etc?

Comment: Sure. The `()` represents extracting a group, which is then referenced as `\\1`, `\\2`, ..., `\\n`'th group to cat them together. Group 1 `(.*_.*_.*?)`: `.*` represents matching any character, any number of times. So it matches anything, then `_`, then anything, then `_` again, then anything, but lazily (`?`), which just means that it stops at the next `_` in the REGEX. Since the 3rd `_` is outside of the captured group (`()`), it will be replaced in the replacement string since I have a hyphen in `\\1-\\2`... I repeated this process so that it replaced the 3rd thought 5th `_`